# Validating File Name and extension by regular expression

Tags: javascript

I dont want to allow special charachters in filename. i am using the following regular expression..

```
 var allowedFiles = [".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".zip", ".rar", ".sql", ".csv", ".wav", ".txt", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".bmp", ".msg", ".jpeg", ".zip"];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var f = files[i];
    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\:])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");
    if (!regex.test(files[i].name.toLowerCase()) || files[i].size > 1024 * 1024 * 10) { // 2MB Max Size
        ret = false;
    }
}
```

it is allowing special characters too

Comment: Try `var regex = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.("+ allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");`

Comment: file name and extension both are without special charachters?

Comment: Remove the `!` in the if condition.

Comment: var regex = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\:\. ])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$") is working fine.. Thank you